# Maximizing production

Tags: calculus, optimization

The total amount produced by a worker during the first t years after being hired is:

$$A=9+11t+0.0064t^2$$

When $t\gt 2$ (the company requires at least a two year commitment for job placement). What duration, $t$, maximizes the average annual production for the worker?

When I try to solve I'm not getting a maximum and I feel like that's not right, can someone help me with this?

Comment: As $t\to\infty$, the total amount $A(t)$ of product produced increases without bound with the rate of production increasing without bound, as $A$ is given by a quadratic.

Comment: Is one of the signs in $A$ wrong?

Comment: No, it's written how it is in my book.

Comment: Something's definitely wrong in the question. (In the book, not in your post) The annual production is $A(t)/t = 9/t + 11 + 0.0064t$, which goes to $+\infty$ as $t$ goes to $+\infty$, so there's no global maximum.